# Appindicator best practices in PyGTK apps

Tags: python, application-development, quickly, pygtk

I have problem adding appindicator to my PyGTK app. When I place [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators#Python_version) into my **init**.py, before gtk.main(), it works, but when I put it in my main window finish_initializing() method, it does not get showed. Any idea why?

If you look at [quickly template](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~quickly-committers/quickly/trunk/view/head:/data/templates/ubuntu-application/project_root/python_lib/Window.py#L72) they suggest to put it in indicator.py. I don't have idea how that file should look like and why it works only in `__init__.py`?

Can someone point me to existing app so I can see code example, I'm interested in best practices for adding appindicator. Example from quickly template looks ok, but not finished.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if they are the best practices or not, but I have done an indicator in python (that falls back to a tray icon when no indicator is supported) [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~javier-isotecsl/notificadorumbria/trunk/files).

It's a very simple program, it just checks a website and changes color (an optionally shows a message) when there are updates on it, so I hope that it could be simple enough to make a good example. It uses by default lib-indicator but it falls back to pure gtk or qt if it isn't present or direct use of some of this libraries is better (it uses qt as its first option if it detects that it's running under KDE or Windows).

I hope that it is somewhat useful.

Comment: Thanks for your example. You answered only one part of my question, but I accepted it anyway. The problem why it was not working for me when put https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators#Python_version inside class is that simple I didn't assign indicator to my window, so it was deleted from memory since no var held the reference to indicator object. Thanks again for your example, I hope someone will find it useful as well.

Comment: One subquestion regarding your app. I see you have icons for dark theme. Did you handle light theme, icons will be almost invisible in light theme, right? Do you know how this should be solved?

Comment: Not really. For sure, whenever you can, you should use stock (from theme) icons, to avoid that kind of problems. But I don't know a way to solve it in all the possible situations (different themes, DEs or OSes). I know some of the users of this program change the icon files to better suit their other icons (they are Windows users). So at least, keep the icons in easy to change files (don't use resource files and the like).

Comment: Thanks. But how can I know which stock icons are available on target machine? Looks like new question should be posted :)

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't much help to me since it's all written in a language other than English (Spanish I think..). +1 anyway though :)

Comment: Yes, comments are in Spanish, but code is in Python ;).

Comment: Yes, but if I am to *understand* the code I must be able to understand the whole thing.. that's all.